# HTML div end tag seen too early closing error

Tags: html

I just started practicing HTML and some CSS,
while working on a task from the course i'm taking online I have encountered an issue with closing a `div`
I have created a .section3 on css

```
font-family: 'Handlee', cursive;
font-size: 13pt;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 15px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

and on the `<body>` i've created a `span` with a `ul` which has inside text and images along with an `a href` and the result looks as desired.

however, while trying to close the `div` I get the following error ```End tag (form) seen too early. Expected other end tag.

the code is as follows;

```
<div class="section2"> 
        <h4><span>COMPLETED COURSES</span></h4>


            <ul>

                    <li> 
                         HTML on <strong>SoloLearn</strong> - <a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/"> <small>link to certificate</small></a>
                          </li>
     <a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/" add target="_blank">
          <img src="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/HTML/jpg/" width="100px" height="65px" alt="">
</a>


                    <li> 
                         SQL on <strong>SoloLearn and Pluralsight</strong> - <a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/">

 <small>link to certificate</small></a>
                          </li>
     <a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/" add target="_blank">
          <img src="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/HTML/jpg/" width="100px" height="65px" alt=""></a>


    <!--error line-->           </div>
```

I tried everything I could, please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You did not close your `<ul>` tag. You should insert `</ul>` tag just before your `</div>`.

```
<div class="section2">
  <h4><span>COMPLETED COURSES</span></h4>

  <ul>
    <li>
      HTML on <strong>SoloLearn</strong> -
      <a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/">
        <small>link to certificate</small></a
      >
    </li>
    <a
      href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/"
      add
      target="_blank"
    >
      <img
        src="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/HTML/jpg/"
        width="100px"
        height="65px"
        alt=""
      />
    </a>

    <li>
      SQL on <strong>SoloLearn and Pluralsight</strong> -
      <a href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/">
        <small>link to certificate</small></a
      >
    </li>
    <a
      href="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/1014-6538353/pdf/"
      add
      target="_blank"
    >
      <img
        src="https://www.sololearn.com/Certificate/HTML/jpg/"
        width="100px"
        height="65px"
        alt=""
    /></a>
  </ul>
  <!--error line-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inside a `<ul>` there can only be multiple `<li>` elements. 
In your code your `<a>` elements are siblings to your `<li>`, try putting them inside.

Then you forgot to close your `<ul>` tag !

My advice for you is to keep your code indented, noticing missing tags will become easier.

Comment: Thanks! the reason the ```<a>``` elements are put there is because the text style, which is ```TEXT - hyperlink``` inside the```<li>``` value
is there a right or better way do so?